# WCF and protobuf with message signification

Tags: c#, wcf, protobuf-net

I have an abstract base class can be serialized using protobuf:

```
[ProtoContract]
class DataPacket
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public byte[] Data {set;get;}
  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public byte[] Sign {set;get;}
  [ProtoMember(3)]
  public long UserId {set;get;}
  [ProtoMember(4)]
  public DateTime Stamp {set;get;}
}
```

The challenge is to make WCF to signify every sended and check signature of every received message. There two static methods in one static class:

```
bool Verify(DataPacket pack)
```

and

```
void Sign(DataPacket pack)
```

So if verification method returns false we need to throw an `Exception` else - default WCF behavior.
Is it possible to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your data packet in a message contract and enforce signing:

```
[MessageContract]
public class {
    [MessageBodyMember(ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
    public byte[] Packet { get; set; }
}
```

WCF will take care of it automatically (calculating the signature and embedding it into SOAP envelop). Of course, Protobuf (de)serialization is up to you.